# How can i write a file in PHP with encode ISO-8859-1?

Tags: php, file, encoding

How can i write a file in PHP with encode ISO-8859-1?

Im using the function

```
$file = fopen("file.txt", "a");
```

When the file is created, it appears with encoding UTF-8 and i want it in ISO-8859-1.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Comment: or just change the encoding of your text editor, if the content is hard-coded in the source of your script

Answer (score -8, accepted):

UTF-8 supports all the characters found in ISO-8859-1... it's best to stick with UTF-8 as it supports the most amount of characters commonly used and will give you the least amount of problems.

Comment: This kind of answers tick me off. Maybe the specified encoding is *required*.
Why giving not-asked-for advice?

Comment: no u ..........